# Hashtables collision resolution

Tags: c#, hashtable

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379571%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#datastructures20_2_topic6) it is stated how hashtable resolves collisions

This sounds ok, untill I think about retrieving results from hashtable.
Lets assume we have following hashtable:

```
[slot 1] = A (hashed with F1)
[slot 2] = B (hashed with F2 because F1 collides with slot 1)
```

Now we want to retrieve B. To retrieve B we need to calculate its hashcode again, but how do we know that we have to use hash function F2 instead of default F1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object stored in the hash table should have the original key in it. So you use H1, find an object, check its key. Not the right one, try with H2. And so on.